# Copy keys to a new dictionary (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm reading a csv file, using DictReader().  The function returns a dictionary, where the header items are the keys and the cells are the values.  Pretty cool.

But I'm trying to account for rows where the data may not be what I expect it to be.  In that case (I'm catching a ValueError exception), I would like the rows that are 'suspect' to go into a separate dictionary, for manual processing.

My question is this: since my first dictionary (the object returned by DictReader) has all of its keys set up properly, how do I copy **just the keys** into my second dictionary, the one which I want to be just a dictionary of suspect rows, to be manually processed?

I've been toying around with dict.fromkeys() and such for a while now and I'm just not getting anywhere.  Halp!

EDIT:  Pasting some of my erroneous code.  Going to go hide in shame of my code.  Don't judge me! ;-)

```
unsure_rows = dict.fromkeys(dict(csv_reader).keys(), [])
for row in csv_reader:
#   if row['Start Time'] != 'None':
    try:
        if before_date > strptime(row['Start Time'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') > after_date:
            continue
    except ValueError:
        unsure_rows += row
```

ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 13; 2 is required

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You are close.  Try:

`dict.fromkeys(my_csv_dict.keys(),[])`

This will initialize a dictionary with the same keys that you parsed from your CSV file, and each one will map to an empty list (to which, I assume, you will append your suspect row values).

---

Try this.  (There are several subtler changes here that are all necessary, like how you can't initialize unsure_rows before you start reading the CSV.)

```
unsure_rows = None
for row in csv_reader:
#   if row['Start Time'] != 'None':
    try:
        if before_date > strptime(row['Start Time'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') > after_date:
            continue
    except ValueError:
        if not unsure_rows:
            # Initialize the unsure rows dictionary
            unsure_rows = dict.fromkeys(csv_reader.fieldnames,[])
        for key in unsure_rows:
            unsure_rows[key].append(row[key])
```

Comment: Hrm.  It seems to be having type errors, I have pasted a portion of the code in question above.

Comment: I want unsure_rows to also be a dictionary, so that I can reference the values easily.

Comment: I understand, but you'll have to clarify further.  In your present code, when you reference a dictionary key, there is only one value to return since you are working with a single row.  But in your `unsure_rows` structure, a single key will be referencing the values of [potentially] numerous rows.  Do you want each dictionary key to map to the list of cell values for the column with which that key is associated?

Comment: Ooh.  Yes, I think that's exactly what I want!

Comment: Hmm.  The problem now is, it seems to have a list nested under a single dictionary key (the first key).  Eg. "{'Status': ['New', 'Donna Beijor', '0.00', '308.00', '0.00', 'None'," etc.

Comment: The first suggestion will add the same list under all keys in the dictionary. Someone is in for a nasty surprise.

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried:

```
newd = dict.fromkeys(origdict)
```

? If that doesn't work for you then please add more details about the error you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't want to copy "just the keys" into another *dictionary*, but if you have "just the keys" you will have a *set*.

To get the keys from dict `d`, you need only say `d.keys()`.

This returns a list (with keys in arbitrary order), which you can keep as a list or copy into a set with

```
set(d.keys())
```

Example:

```
>>> d = {'one': 1, 'three': 3, 'two': 2, 'four': 4} 
>>> set(d.keys())
set(['four', 'one', 'three', 'two'])
```

**EDIT**:

Now I see that you intend to capture suspect key-value pairs as you catch exceptions.  In this case, just start with an empty dictionary

```
suspect = {}
```

And inside your code, which I would imagine is some kind of loop, add the suspect key value pairs like so:

```
while something():
    k, v = generate_pair()
    try:
        analyze_something_with_k_and_v_that_might_throw_an_exception
        add_it_to_regular_dict
    except:
        suspect[k] = v
```

Comment: Arg.  Badly formed question.  As I catch the exceptions, I want to append them into my 2nd dictionary.  You're right, that means I don't want to just copy the keys, or to have a set.  My train of thought is that the dictionary needs to have at least the keys, so that I can append the values later.  Am I wrong?

Comment: Oh, I see.  Just start with an empty dictionary, and add the suspect key-value pairs one by one as you detect them.  I've updated the answer to show this.

Answer (score 1):

The solution from cheeken isn't working anymore as  `dict.fromkeys` is creating the dictionary with all values pointing to the same list you should instead use `{k: [] for k in my_csv_dict.keys()}`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30718843)